# Why does the render not fill up the whole canvas?

Tags: rendering, animation

[image]I rendered an image sequence and this is what keeps happening

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: You've probably set a rendering region.

Comment: Apart from using proper screenshots it would be helpful to give us more information what you did there and how the scene looks like in the viewport. From what I see I cannot tell if this a scene with a model which should fill the complete frame or a plane with an image (sequence) on it and it is smaller than the full frame? etc...